# how to copy android kernel config from our device

Tags: android

i am using LiMe to acquire android ram dump.
i had set up the enviornment.
now i am preparing the kernel source.
i am using samsung device model no:GT-I9000 firmware version:2.1-update-1.
i downloaded GT-I9000-update.3.0.zip(don't know whether it is correct choice).

i tried to copy the android kernel config from the device.
using the following code in the ubuntu terminal.
sudo ./adb pull/proc/config.gz.

but not done an error occurred.
"remote object /proc/config.gz does not exist

please help me to solve the problem

Comment: You are getting this error because the image you are using on your device does not contain the kernel config file. Maybe because the vendor didn't provide for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
adb shell cat /proc/version
```